# render an action from clicking a button without reloading page: Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im using ajax to make a controller action when clicked without reloading page. I cant seem to get the js view to be rendered.

transactions_controller:

```rails
require "braintree"

    def index   
       @reservations = Reservation.where("transaction_id = transaction_id", true)

    end

    def escrow
        @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
        @escrow = Braintree::Transaction.release_from_escrow(@reservation.transaction_id)
        @reservation.update_attributes pay_completed: true
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js { render :layout=>false }
        end 
    end

    private
    def reservation
        @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end
```

My link on index.html.erb:

```html
<% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
   <% @transaction = Braintree::Transaction.find(reservation.transaction_id) %>
   
  
  <tr>
  <td><%= reservation.id %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.transaction_id %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.reviser.user.username %></td>

    <td><%= reservation.user.username %></td>
    <td><%= @transaction.status %></td>
    <td><%= @transaction.escrow_status %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.completed %></td>
<td><%= link_to "stock", escrow_path(reservation), :remote => true %></td>
    
  </tr>
  
   

   

   

   <% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'admin/transactions' => 'admin/transactions#index' 
patch 'admin/transactions/:id' => 'admin/transactions#escrow', :as => 'escrow'
```

escrow.js:

```
$('#escrow').html("<%= j (render @escrow) %>");
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong! thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but advice on where to go from here:

What you need to do from here is start narrowing down where the issue takes place. You know that when you click your link, it doesn't do what you want. Now, go through step by step and see where something goes wrong. Update your question with answers to the following:

1. If you switch off ajax (remote => false) does it work?

Now, with ajax switched on:

2. Does clicking the link send a request to the server at all? (Use Chrome dev tools to check this) Is the request what you'd expect?
3. Does your rails server receive any kind of request? View the logs after you click the link, to see if anything at all happens. If it does, what? Does it look like a successful request?
4. If you just replace the code in escrow.js with a simple `alert('got here');`, does it execute?

Comment: in my logs when i click i get                                                                           app/admin/transactions.rb:26:in `block in escrow'
  app/admin/transactions.rb:25:in `escrow'

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
# escrow.js.erb
var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'escrow', locals: { escrow_var: @escrow } ) %>"
$('#escrow').html(html);
```

You should have a partial called `_escrow.html.erb` and use `escrow_var` inside the partial instead of `@scrow`.

You can use any other names, of course.